# Combine shaders with directx 11

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

Is there a way to combine shaders?

Let's say i want to have 4 models :

- One with just the texture rendered.
- One with the texture and a basic light effect.
- One rendered with skeletal animation.
- One rendered with skeletal animation and basic light effect.

The only way i know to do that, is to create 4 pixel and vertex shaders files. But is i have 5 more effects that i want to add, i must created more files, and if i want to add more and more effects? I doubt that for each effect i have to create one more file for each possibility. I know that for the light i can set it directly in the other files, and when i dont want to use light, i set it to 1.0f so the color dont change. But if i want to have more effects, i will have like 20 variables in my shader, and isn't that useless if i dont use them? Is there another way to do that?

Thanks in advance, i tried to be as understandable as i could, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts:

- Move common functionality to separate file and use `#include` to spread it between shaders.
- Use `#ifdef` for conditional compilation. Pass defines via `/D` flag of `fxc.exe` of `D3D_SHADER_MACRO` of `D3DCompile`. You can combine all in one shader and then compile it into many different binaries.
- Use some effect framework (default DirectX one, googled or make your own): you will not need separate files for shaders, all goes in one file, so as states.
- Leave all as is: HLSL is complicated and any more complications just can lead to unmaintainable mess.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah it does. Fortunately i dont really need some shaders, i was just wondering on what was the common way to do it, but after read your post and the link below, i guess there is no common way ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/08/17/combining-shaders.aspx ). Thanks for the help btw.